# A more effificent approach to Nested loops in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-loops

I have a nested loop that I am trying to make  more efficient.
I need to find a way to speed up execution - I think the issue is the fact I need to hash both values to do my comparison to find the correct value.

Is there an easier way to do this?

I have tried different ways of concatenating the values - assigning values at different points but I am not seeing any true time savings.

```
    for val1 in text_list:
        for val2 in text_list:
            hashed_text = hashlib.sha256(val1.encode() + val2.encode()).hexdigest()
            if hashed_text == expected_value:
                return val1, val2
```

The input file is 1K + entries and take ~1 second I need to find a way to cut down the execution time.

Answer (score 0):

if you had added some examples i could have tested and benchmarked this. without that here is something untested that may help: it reduces the hash calculation of `val1`:

```
for val1 in text_list:
    h = hashlib.sha256(val1.encode())
    for val2 in text_list:
        h2 = h.copy()
        h2.update(val2.encode())
        hashed_text = h2.hexdigest()
        if hashed_text == expected_value:
            return val1, val2
```

but as i said i can not test if this helps in your case...